# опять не пойму что хотят в задании в книге Б. Эккеля

Tags: c++

вот есть программа, предназначеная для автоматизации управления блоками памяти:
состоит из заголовочника и реализации.

заголовочник:

```
#ifndef MEM_H
#define MEM_H
typedef unsigned char byte;

class Mem {
    byte* mem;
    int size;
    bool move;
    void ensureMinSize(int minSize);
public:
    Mem();
    Mem(int sz);
    ~Mem();
    int msize();
    byte* pointer();
    byte* pointer(int minSize);
    bool moved();
};
#endif
```

реализация класса :

```
#include <cstring>
#include "Mem.h"
using namespace std;

Mem::Mem() { mem = 0; size = 0; }

Mem::Mem(int sz) {
  mem = 0;
  size = 0;
  ensureMinSize(sz); 
}

Mem::~Mem() { delete []mem; }

int Mem::msize() { return size; }

void Mem::ensureMinSize(int minSize) {
  if(size < minSize) {
    byte* newmem = new byte[minSize];
    memset(newmem + size, 0, minSize - size);
    memcpy(newmem, mem, size);
    delete []mem;
    mem = newmem;
    size = minSize;
  }
}

byte* Mem::pointer() { return mem; }

byte* Mem::pointer(int minSize) {
  ensureMinSize(minSize);
  return mem; 
} ///:~
```

кратенькое описание копипастил из книги :
Объект Mеm содержит байтовый буфер и следит за тем, чтобы объем буфера
был достаточным. Конструктор по умолчанию вообще не выделяет память, а второй
конструктор выделяет блок объемом sz. Деструктор освобождает память, функция
msize() сообщает текущий размер буфера в байтах, а функция pointer() возвращает
указатель на начальный адрес буфера (объект Mеm работает на достаточно
низком уровне). Также существует перегруженная версия pointer(), при помощи
которой прикладной программист указывает, что ему нужен указатель на буфер
объемом не менее minSize; перегруженная версия функции pointer() автоматически
обеспечивает выполнение этого условия.
И конструктор, и функция pointer() увеличивают размер буфера при помощи
закрытой функции ensureMinSize() (обратите внимание, что из-за возможного перераспределения
памяти сохранять результат pointer() небезопасно).

а вот теперь само задание :
Включите в класс Mеm функцию bool moved(), которая получает результат
вызова pointer() и сообщает, был ли перемещен указатель (вследствие перераспределения
памяти). Напишите функцию main() для тестирования функции
moved(). Что разумнее, использовать функции типа moved() или просто
вызывать pointer каждый раз, когда потребуется обратиться к памяти в Mеm?

мне это задание совершенно непонятно.
ну вот я введу свойство bool move . буду его менять в методе ensureMinSize в случае если сработает условие
(size < minSize) . метод moved будет выдавать это свойство. символизировать оно будет, что было только что
перераспределение памяти и теперь главный вопрос :
а кто будет сбрасывать move в значение false ?

Comment: Мне кажется имелось ввиду, что `bool moved()` возвращает `true`, если `byte* mem` был смещен на новое место в памяти (так бывает при перераспределении, вследствие этого все старые указатели на ресурс будут инвалидированы). Значит переменная `move` по умолчанию должна иметь значение `false` Если обнаружено изменение указателя - становится `true`. В функции `pointer()` можно изменять обратно на `false`, считая, что программистом получена последняя версия указателя.

Comment: Не читайте такие книги, есть же Страуструп. Все задания уже давно решены, если возникнут вопросы

Comment: @Стас спасибо за ответ. ты наверно имеешь ввиду в условие (size < minSize) метода ensureMinSize  вставить move = true; , в pointer поставить move = false; 
то есть вот так как ниже. Однако , непонятно практическое применение этого - что это даёт и как этим пользоваться :)

Comment: @Стас, то есть ты так предлагаешь ? если да , то что это даст ? ))))
void Mem::ensureMinSize(int minSize) {
  if(size < minSize) {
    byte* newmem = new byte[minSize];
    memset(newmem + size, 0, minSize - size);
    memcpy(newmem, mem, size);
    delete []mem;
    mem = newmem;
    size = minSize;
    move = true; 
  }
}
byte* Mem::pointer() { move = false; return mem; }

byte* Mem::pointer(int minSize) {
  move = false;
  ensureMinSize(minSize);
  return mem; 
} ///:~